# How to move the time and date displayed in the tab-bar a couple of character to the left

Tags: frames, display, tabbar, mode-line-format

I would like to move the time and date displayed in the tab-bar a couple of characters to the left, so that the time is not completely on the edge of the screen. Here is the relevant code :

```
(setq tab-bar-format '(tab-bar-format-history
               tab-bar-format-tabs
               tab-bar-separator
               tab-bar-format-align-right
               tab-bar-format-global))
```

As recommended in the manual, I use `tab-bar-format-align-right` but I do not know enough elisp to change its behavior to achieve the desired output.

Update:

I use the following code to configure the time and date :

```
(use-package time
  :commands world-clock
  :config
  (setq display-time-format "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
  (setq display-time-interval 60)
  (setq display-time-mail-directory nil)
  (setq display-time-default-load-average nil)
  :hook (after-init . display-time-mode))
```

However changing the display-time-format variable to be `(setq display-time-format "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M   ")` does not produce the desired output.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You should avoid asking more than one question. Just create a second question for it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will move the second question in another thead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. I have redefined `tab-bar-format-align-right` and subtracted a few pixels, like @link0ff suggested. I have replaced `:align-to (- right ,hpos)` with `:align-to (- right ,hpos 3)`. Below is the full code:

```
(eval-after-load "tab-bar"
(defun tab-bar-format-align-right ()
  "Align the rest of tab bar items to the right."
  (let* ((rest (cdr (memq 'tab-bar-format-align-right tab-bar-format)))
         (rest (tab-bar-format-list rest))
         (rest (mapconcat (lambda (item) (nth 2 item)) rest ""))
         (hpos (length rest))
         (str (propertize " " 'display `(space :align-to (- right ,hpos 3)))))
    `((align-right menu-item ,str ignore)))))
```

Here is a picture of the result:
[image: Screenshot result]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to customize the variable `display-time-format`. This is the format string used to display the time in either the tab-bar or the modeline, whichever you have configured. The default is just `"%H:%M"`, so that it shows the hour and minutes. If you change it to `"%H:%M   "` then the spaces after it will push it away from the edge of the frame.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I had already tried that before asking the question and it does not work. I have updated the OP accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried other space characters such as `NO-BREAK SPACE`? If this doesn't work, then you need to modify `tab-bar-format-align-right` and subtract more pixels as much as you need.

Comment: I have tried using non-breakable spaces and it worked but this also required to set `nobreak-char-display` to nil, which I did not like.

Answer (score 0):

I realized now there is a much simpler way to pad with whitespace on the right edge.  You can just add more separators to the end.  For example:

```elisp
(setq tab-bar-format
      '(tab-bar-format-history
        tab-bar-format-tabs
        tab-bar-separator
        tab-bar-format-align-right
        tab-bar-format-global
        tab-bar-separator
        tab-bar-separator
        tab-bar-separator
        ))
```

Comment: That is a good solution, but it does not work for me since I do not want any separators between tabs so I have `(setq tab-bar-separator "")` in my configuration.